# git - after making some edits, I commited and then tried to push, but got message that everything is up to date

Tags: git

I just made some changes, then commited, but then when I tried to push, I got an error that everything is up to date.

Why would this happen?  As a note, yesterday I had some merge issues and today I had to do a git checkout some_version_number

Any idea what is going wrong here?
Thanks!

Here is the output from git status

```
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Marketing/en.lproj/MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Marketing.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/owner12.xcuserdatad/
```

And then when I try to go to my branch by doing git checkout master, I get this:

```
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git push origin master
Password for 'https://genadinik@bitbucket.org': 
Everything up-to-date
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Marketing/en.lproj/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Marketing.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/owner12.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
```

Comment: What's git status say?

Comment: have you staged the edited files to be pushed 


    git add modified-file.py 
    git commit -m "Adding File "
    git push

Comment: and what exact commands did you use to commit and push?

Comment: @parkydr I just posted the output from git status in the original question.

Comment: To commit, I just used git commit file_names

Comment: And just to note, something is not right with the MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard file because I was working on it yesterday and I had lost the changes on it because of some merge and pull issues I had.

Comment: You're not on any branch, I wonder if that's the problem

Comment: @parkydr I just tried to go to a branch by doing git checkout branch_name, but got error that I added to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your `git status` output, you've made those changes whilst you weren't on the master branch:

```
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
...
```

The reason that your `git checkout` isn't moving you to the `master` branch is because doing so would involve overwriting the changes you've made (as per the error message).

Your easiest way out of this is:

```
$ git stash save      # Save the edits made whilst not on a branch
$ git checkout master # Move to the master branch
$ git stash pop       # Apply stashed-changes; delete from stash if successful
```

Note that applying your changes may cause conflicts - be sure to carefully read any git output.

(EDIT: Note that `git stash save` will not deal with untracked files)

Comment: after doing the stash-save, the checkout master command had an error message: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
 Marketing.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/owner12.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.

Comment: and the stash save command had output that there were no changes to save. :(

Comment: `git stash` won't stash untracked-files, and you've got the same problem as before. Given you've already stashed the tracked files, just move that untracked file out of the way, `git checkout`, move it back.

Comment: sorry I got confused :) ...should I just do git checkout? What will that do? And what should I do after that?

Comment: I strongly recommend getting a graphical git client (e.g. [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/)) so you can see the state of your repository.

Comment: I think you meant `git stash pop` not `apply`, yes?

Comment: Either would work, but `pop` would probably be better here; I shall edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
git add FILENAME
```

Or

```
git commit -a
```

Otherwise you have commited nothing.

Your git output is telling you that you have unstaged and untracked files, which is the case because you just did a "git commit filename" which won't do anything unless you had the file staged with git add.

You could also see this via

```
git log
```

Where the history of your local would be the same as the remote, hence the git message of "everything up to date, no changes"

Comment: are these commands for a new file? I already have that file in the repo.

Comment: I still get the same error when I push which is "Everything up-to-date"

Comment: -1; the problem here is clearly that the OP can't push changes to the master branch if they're not making any changes to the master branch (which they're not, because they've got a detached-HEAD).